# Package/bundle a NodeJS application that uses prisma?

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma

I have a typescript project (a small CLI application) that uses prisma. I can compile (`tsc`) the project and run it (`node build/index.js`) just fine, but I want to package it to a small (preferably just 1) file and send it to my server to run it there.

I am trying to package it to a single executable (using `pkg --targets node16-linux-x64 . --out-path bin/`), but if I try to run this executable I get this error message:

> Unable to load Node-API Library from /snapshot/device_data_reader/node_modules/.prisma/client/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x.so.node, Library may be corrupt

So it seems that the prisma library isn't properly included in the binary? Or that I need to ship some lib files with it?

How can I package/bundle a NodeJS application that uses prisma?

EDIT: Running `uname -a` yields this:

> Linux desktop 5.4.0-109-generic #123-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 8 09:10:54 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

`node --version`:

v16.15.0

Comment: Are the source and destination platforms similar (same CPU architecture/OS, at least)? Prisma apparently uses a compiled library that will likely be platform-dependent.

Comment: Pretty sure. I added some extra info to my question. It's node 16, linux, x64. You're probably onto something about the compiled library, it's probably not included in the binary package...